# Definition of $\mathbf{Z}$-multilinear mapping

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, definition, multilinear-algebra

> Let $(G_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in L}$ be a (not necessarily finite)
> family of $\mathbf{Z}$-modules, $H$ a $\mathbf{Z}$-module and
> $u:\prod_{\lambda\in L}G_\lambda\rightarrow H$. If for each $\mu\in
>  L$, $x,y\in G_\mu$ and $z\in\prod_{\lambda\ne\mu}G_{\lambda}$
> $$u(x+y,(z_{\lambda})_{\lambda\ne\mu})=u(x,(z_{\lambda})_{\lambda\ne\mu})+u(y,(z_{\lambda})_{\lambda\ne\mu}),$$
> where $\prod_{\lambda\in L}G_\lambda$ is identified with
> $G_\mu\times\prod_{\lambda\ne\mu}G_\lambda$, then $u$ is called
> $\mathbf{Z}$-multilinear.

Is there a way to transform this definition into one that doesn't identify $\prod_{\lambda\in L}G_\lambda$ with $G_\mu\times\prod_{\lambda\ne\mu}G_\lambda$?

Comment: Well, $u$ can be considered as a function in $|L|$ variables, and the condition says that it's additive in each variable (when the rest is fixed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is effectively just a rephrasing of the definition you gave without using the identification between $\prod_{\lambda\in L}G_\lambda$ and $G_\mu\times\prod_{\lambda\neq\mu}G_\lambda$.

> Let $(G_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in L}$ be a (not necessarily finite)
> family of $\mathbf{Z}$-modules, $H$ a $\mathbf{Z}$-module and
> $u:\prod_{\lambda\in L}G_\lambda\rightarrow H$. If for each $\mu\in
>  L$ and $z\in\prod_{\lambda\in L}G_{\lambda}$, we have
> $$u((z_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in L})=u((z'_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in L})+u((z''_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in L}),$$
> whenever $z_\mu=z'_\mu+z''_\mu$ and $z_\lambda=z'_\lambda=z''_\lambda$ for all $\lambda\neq \mu$, then $u$ is called
> $\mathbf{Z}$-multilinear.