# A mistake in Bourbaki's construction of general tensor product?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Fortunately someone seems to have a asked a similar question before here: [Bourbaki's construction of generalized tensor product of modules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3720917/bourbakis-construction-of-generalized-tensor-product-of-modules) ; to save space and time, I will use the same notation and terminology.

I will begin where the other question ended. After defining $\bigotimes^{(c,p,q)}_{\lambda\in L}G_\lambda$, Bourbaki writes the following:

> [image]

Then we are given details of the associativity properties:

> [image]
>
> [image]

The existence of the claimed isomorphism is then proved by induction on $n$. The proof of the base case is easy. **However, I have found that "permutability hypothesis (P)" is not enough to allow the proof in the induction step.** To highlight this, I will try to show that the case $n=3$ doesn't reduce to a routine application of the result for $n=2$.

So, let all notation be as before and let $n=3$. That is to say, let $(L_1,L_2,L_3)$ be a partition of $L$. Then $(L_1\cup L_2,L_3)$ is also a partition of $L$ and we should be able to apply the result for $n=2$, right? But this is not possible! What do we need to apply $n=2$ result? We need the following:

1. A family $(G_\lambda)_{\lambda\in L}$ of abelian groups;
2. A mapping $c:\Omega\rightarrow L\times L$;
3. Two mappings $p\in\prod_{\omega\in\Omega}\text{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(E_{\rho(\omega)})$ and $q\in\prod_{\omega\in\Omega}\text{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(E_{\sigma(\omega)})$ satisfying a corresponding form of hypothesis (P).

The problem is that (3) is not satisfied. By assumption, we are given a map $c:\Omega\rightarrow L\times L$ and the two mapping $p,q$. Then we have
$$\Omega_1=c^{-1}(L_1\times L_1)\cup c^{-1}(L_1\times L_2)\cup c^{-1}(L_2\times L_1)\cup c^{-1}(L_2\times L_2)\text{ and }\Omega_2=c^{-1}(L_3\times L_3).$$
Now, let us see whether the corresponding hypothesis (P) holds for this partition and mappings. Fix $\omega\in\Omega-(\Omega_1\cup\Omega_2)$, say, $\omega\in c^{-1}(L_1\times L_3)$. Let $\xi\in\Omega_1\cup\Omega_2$, say, $\xi\in c^{-1}(L_1\times L_2)$. We need, for example, for
$$p_\omega\circ p_\xi=p_\xi\circ p_\omega$$
to hold, but we have no reason to deduce that it does. By assumption we only have the above identity for $\xi\in c^{-1}(L_i\times L_i)\cap\rho^{-1}(\{\rho(\omega)\})$ for $i=1,2,3$ for a fixed $\omega$ not in sets of the form $c^{-1}(L_i\times L_i)$. The same problem exists for the other identities.

So, it's clear that hypothesis (P) in the form given by Bourbaki is not enough. Am I correct? Does anyone know how to fix it?

**EDIT:** You can find this in Algebra I p.259-264.